# Having a little bit of trouble with the output of my code

Tags: java

I'm trying here to print out the values of 1 squared by 10, 10 squared by 10, 100 squared by 10, and so forth. But in my output I keep getting the values in double instead of int (whole numbers) which is what Im supposed to do.

```
public class PowerGenerator {
    int factor;

    public PowerGenerator(int aFactor) {
        factor = aFactor; 
    }

    public double nextPower() {
        if(factor < 0.9) {
            factor = 1.0; // This is where the compiler has an error.
            return 1;
        }

        factor = factor * 10;
        return factor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PowerGenerator test= new PowerGenerator(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            System.out.println(test.nextPower());
        }
    }
}
```

The output of my code is:

```
1.0
10.0
100.0
1000.0
10000.0
100000.0
1000000.0
1.0E7
1.0E8
1.0E9
1.0E10
1.0E11
```

Comment: `factor` is an `int`. Is **`1.0`** an `int`?

Comment: Whenever i change 1.0 to 1, my output becomes:                            
'1.0
10.0
100.0
1000.0
10000.0
100000.0
1000000.0
1.0E7
1.0E8
1.0E9
1.410065408E9
1.215752192E9'

Comment: What output do you want? `1 10 100 1000 ....` why use an `int` if what you want is to keep appending `0` to a `String`?

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to set the output to 1 10 100 1000 etc.

Comment: @BrandonCortes-Ramirez Then let `nextPower()` return an `int` instead of a `double`

Comment: @Ivar how would I go about doing that? I just can’t seem to figure it out.

Comment: `public double nextPower()` --> `public int nextPower()`

Comment: @Ivar that seems to have fixed it. Thank you tons for the help!

Comment: @Ivar I've fixed the double problem, but now with my output my last two values are as follows:                                                             
`1410065408
1215752192`                                                                                                But I need them to be:                                                                                    `100000000
1000000000`

Comment: You say your assignment requires you to use an int. But int has a limited value range and simply can not accommodate the last 2 values that you were expecting. You’re seeing an example of numerical overflow.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt How would I go about compensating for the numerical overflow? Would I need to change the data type?

Comment: Yes - you could use `long` or `BigInteger`